# How to add two dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

If the input is

```
d1={'A':5,'B':6,'C':8}
d2={'A':4,'B':9,'E':2}
```

I want the output to be

```
d3={'A':9,'B':15,'C':8,'E':2}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, please read how to ask a question here (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Do you have any attempt you have made yet?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
>>> fst = {'A': 5, 'B': 6, 'C': 8}
>>> snd = {'A': 4, 'B': 9, 'E': 2}
>>> out = {k: fst[k] + snd[k] for k in fst.keys() & snd.keys()}
>>> out.update({k: fst[k] if k in fst else snd[k] for k in fst.keys() ^ snd.keys()})
>>> out
{'A': 9, 'B': 15, 'C': 8, 'E': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for counting:

```
from collections import Counter

d3 = Counter(d1) + Counter(d2)

Counter({'A': 9, 'B': 15, 'C': 8, 'E': 2})
```

Since `Counter` is a subclass of `dict`, you will likely not want to convert this explicitly to a regular `dict`. There are some limitations, namely `Counter` works only with positive integers.